# Kafka stream failover

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

What are the best practices to migrate kafka stream applications to another secondary cluster for failover purposes? And any precautions to take?
Also requirement is that application should continue consumption where it left off in primary.

Use some tools like replicator or mirror maker to replicate changelog topics to secondary cluster.

Comment: Add more tags or none gonna see this question.

Comment: You need to replicate RocksDB storage as well. You cannot failover disks very easily. How likely are you expecting the cluster, with all its replicas, to become unavailable?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would it be necessary to replicate RocksDB storage, I believe it would be able to create states in RocksDB by reading changelog topic from scratch when application is started in target (remote) ?